Recurrence formula of matrices
A matrix ${\bf A}_n$ is defined by the recurrence formula
$$
{\bf A}_{n+1}={\bf F}{\bf A}_{n} - {\bf A}_{n-1}
$$
where ${\bf F}$ is also a matrix and ${\bf A}_{-1}=\bf{0}$ and ${\bf A}_0=\bf{I}$.
Can we obtain explicit formula of ${\bf A}_n$?

What is your work on this subject ?

I am calculating the characteristic equation (2.2) in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0217

See here. Besides, have you attempted to treat the case of numbers ($1 \times 1$ matrices) ?

Yes. I used the well-known matrix-based solution method for the Fibonacci sequence. I am having trouble because the nth power of the matrix contains the root symbol when it is not a 1x1 matrix.

Does $F$ satisfy some particular properties ?

@Abezhiko The matrix ${\bf F}$ can be written as ${\bf F}={\bf C}^{-1} (x{\bf I} - {\bf B} )$ using two non-singular matrices ${\bf C}$ and ${\bf B}$ and the variable $x$.

Have you tried to compute the associated generating function ?

Yes. But I am having trouble because the nth power of the matrix contains the root symbol when it is not a 1x1 matrix.

I drew some pictures,  sort of slanted Pascal's Triangle
$$ {\bf A}_n =  \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \; (-1)^j \; \left( 
\;\begin{array}{c} 
n-j  \\ 
j  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; 
{\bf F}^{n-2j}
$$
also alternate zero coefficients,  hence the $n-2j$  exponent
